# How to swap out simple SVG icons when it's clicked using HTML, CSS, and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, icons

This is an elementary question, but after reading other people's questions, articles and tutorials, I'm still in the dark when it comes to inline SVG icons and how to properly handle them in HTML, CSS, and jQuery.

**My goal:** when I click **+ icon**, it changes to **–icon**.

**What I did:** I downloaded two SVG icons from Noun project. Then I added the code for **+ icon** in my HTML markup. Here is what it looks like so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/461jaLxt/

```
<div class="border"></div>
                <div class="clickableList">
                    <span class="types">Swap icons</span>
                    <svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 74 74" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                        <title>noun_1776266_cc</title>
                        <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
                        <defs></defs>
                        <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                            <g id="noun_1776266_cc_2" transform="translate(0.000000, -1.000000)" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero">
                                <g id="Group" transform="translate(0.000000, 0.637820)">
                                    <polygon id="Shape" points="33 0.36218 33 33.36218 0 33.36218 0 41.3622 33 41.3622 33 74.3622 41 74.3622 41 41.3622 74 41.3622 74 33.36218 41 33.36218 41 0.36218 33 0.36218"></polygon>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </div>

.types {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
}

$('.clickableList').click(function() {
event.preventDefault();
```

Now I have to add the second icon, and this part is what I've been stuck on for a while. Below is the markup for the second icon but I can't figure out how and where to add it in my html so later when the first icon is clicked, it would change to this second icon.

```
<!-- second SVG-->
<svg width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 74 74" version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<title>noun_line_1776294</title>
<desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
<defs></defs>
<g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <g id="noun_line_1776294" transform="translate(-6.000000, -31.000000)">
        <g id="Group" transform="translate(0.000000, 0.637820)">
            <polygon id="Shape" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" points="6 30.36218 6 38.36218 68 38.36218 68 30.36218"></polygon>
            <rect id="Rectangle" x="0" y="0" width="74" height="69"></rect>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first, jQuery is just a library (a collection of scripts that allow you to do new things easily). It's the most commonly-used Javascript library by far, so people often confuse it with Javascript itself. You program in Javascript, and you use jQuery to make it (much!) easier to modify HTML elements and many other things.

I would actually recommend you use [Font Awesome icons](https://fontawesome.com/) rather than hard-coded SVG as it'll be a lot easier to work with, but since you ask, this is one of the simplest ways to change your plus sign into a minus sign:

http://jsfiddle.net/461jaLxt/6/

```js
$('.clickableList').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#svgPlus').toggle();
   $('#svgMinus').toggle();
});
```

```css
.types {
   font-size: 20px;
   font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="border">
   <div class="clickableList">
      <span class="types">Swap icons</span>
      <svg id="svgPlus" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 74 74" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
         <title>noun_1776266_cc</title>
         <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
         <defs></defs>
         <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g id="noun_1776266_cc_2" transform="translate(0.000000, -1.000000)" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero">
               <g id="Group" transform="translate(0.000000, 0.637820)">
                  <polygon id="Shape" points="33 0.36218 33 33.36218 0 33.36218 0 41.3622 33 41.3622 33 74.3622 41 74.3622 41 41.3622 74 41.3622 74 33.36218 41 33.36218 41 0.36218 33 0.36218"></polygon>
               </g>
            </g>
         </g>
      </svg>
      <svg id="svgMinus" style="display: none;" width="20px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 74 74" version="1.1" 
         xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
         <title>noun_line_1776294</title>
         <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
         <defs></defs>
         <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g id="noun_line_1776294" transform="translate(-6.000000, -31.000000)">
               <g id="Group" transform="translate(0.000000, 0.637820)">
                  <polygon id="Shape" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" points="6 30.36218 6 38.36218 68 38.36218 68 30.36218"></polygon>
                  <rect id="Rectangle" x="0" y="0" width="74" height="69"></rect>
               </g>
            </g>
         </g>
      </svg>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

### How does it work?

Basically when you click it all it does is hide the plus and show the minus, and vice versa if you click again. If you look at the second SVG element in the example above, you'll see it has `style="display: none;"`, which is [inline CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) to make an element hidden to begin with (that's why the minus is invisible at the start). In order to swap which is being shown, we use jQuery's [toggle() function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), which shows an element if it's hidden and hides it otherwise.

Comment: To help the OP, I suggest you add a bit more information on how it works. For example, what `toggle()` actually does, and why the minus icon is not visible at first.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Whoops, definitely meant to add some more information there before posting. Thanks for calling that out!

Comment: Incidentally, you don't neeed a Fiddle if you have a snippet: the snippet contains a JS runner itself. I have made a small code amendment to fix a JS error.

Comment: @halfer Good point about the Fiddle. I was aware of that but started with the Fiddle before remembering about snippets and forgot to remove the Fiddle. Also good catch on the JS error; that was part of the OP's code and I didn't notice it.

Comment: @Clonkex, thank you so much for the solution along with the clear explanation! I am going to take time to read your answer and inspect the code. I will check out Font Awesome icons as well. Thank you!

Comment: @Takine How'd you go? Just want to check if you need more help or if my explanation solved your problem (if this did answer your question, you can click the check mark next to the answer to select it as the correct solution) :)

Comment: @Clonkex, your explanation solved my problem, and I clicked the check mark next to the answer! :-)

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!